# Equivalent of transform in R/ddply in Python/pandas?

Tags: python, r, pandas, plyr

In R's ddply function, you can compute any new columns group-wise, and append the result to the original dataframe, such as:

```
ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), transform, n=length(cyl)) # n is appended to the df
```

In Python/pandas, I have computed it first, and then merge, such as:

```
df1 = mtcars.groupby("cyl").apply(lambda x: Series(x["cyl"].count(), index=["n"])).reset_index()
mtcars = pd.merge(mtcars, df1, on=["cyl"])
```

or something like that.

However, I always feel like that's pretty daunting, so is it feasible to do it all once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can add a column to a DataFrame by assigning the result of a groupby/transform operation to it:

```
mtcars['n'] = mtcars.groupby("cyl")['cyl'].transform('count')
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.rpy.common as com

mtcars = com.load_data('mtcars')
mtcars['n'] = mtcars.groupby("cyl")['cyl'].transform('count')
print(mtcars.head())
```

yields

```
                    mpg  cyl  disp   hp  drat     wt   qsec  vs  am  gear  carb   n
Mazda RX4          21.0    6   160  110  3.90  2.620  16.46   0   1     4     4   7
Mazda RX4 Wag      21.0    6   160  110  3.90  2.875  17.02   0   1     4     4   7
Datsun 710         22.8    4   108   93  3.85  2.320  18.61   1   1     4     1  11
Hornet 4 Drive     21.4    6   258  110  3.08  3.215  19.44   1   0     3     1   7
Hornet Sportabout  18.7    8   360  175  3.15  3.440  17.02   0   0     3     2  14
```

---

To add multiple columns, you could use `groupby/apply`. Make sure the function you apply returns a DataFrame with the same index as its input. For example,

```
mtcars[['n','total_wt']] = mtcars.groupby("cyl").apply(
    lambda x: pd.DataFrame({'n': len(x['cyl']), 'total_wt': x['wt'].sum()},
                           index=x.index))
print(mtcars.head())
```

yields

```
                    mpg  cyl  disp   hp  drat     wt   qsec  vs  am  gear  carb   n  total_wt
Mazda RX4          21.0    6   160  110  3.90  2.620  16.46   0   1     4     4   7    21.820
Mazda RX4 Wag      21.0    6   160  110  3.90  2.875  17.02   0   1     4     4   7    21.820
Datsun 710         22.8    4   108   93  3.85  2.320  18.61   1   1     4     1  11    25.143
Hornet 4 Drive     21.4    6   258  110  3.08  3.215  19.44   1   0     3     1   7    21.820
Hornet Sportabout  18.7    8   360  175  3.15  3.440  17.02   0   0     3     2  14    55.989
```

Comment: Awesome! Then let me ask one more question... is it feasible to calculate multiple columns once, such as `ddply(mtcars, .(cyl), transform, n=length(cyl), total_wt=sum(wt))`?

Comment: The syntax is not as pithy as `R`'s is, but I've added an example above to show how.